# C++ use of Eigen in tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

What is the relation between tensorflow and Eigen, particularly regarding the `tensor` datastructures?

There are some older quotations (e.g. [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1mqPhiqnSAhUhBMAKHdMBCqMQFggrMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.tensorflow.org%2Fpaper%2Fwhitepaper2015.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEAFa6vGrlp_CKFlVxs0EHLsyhVtQ&bvm=bv.147448319,bs.1,d.d2s)) which state that tensorflow is using Eigen extensively (afaik a tensorflow guy has extended the Eigen code). More recent tensorflow documentation, however, seems to not explicitly refer to Eigen.

Are the two `tensor` structures identical? Are they being updated concurrently? Is there any (possibly future) disadvantage in using the `Eigen::tensor` over the `tensorflow::tensor`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`tensorflow::tensor` is just a thin wrapper around `Eigen::Tensor` with limited high-level features only. You can access to the underlying `Eigen::Tensor` of a `tensorflow::tensor` using the `tensor()` method. I guess that this information also solve your last two questions.